Opening any yaml file in VSCode opens tons of Chromium screens to login
I am not sure what is causing this but eacvh time I open a yaml file in VSCode, it just opens several instances (sometimes 15-20) of Chromium engine.

I have created a gif to show what is happening. I have removed a lot of extensions and only have a few basic ones (re-installed them again) like Flutter, Prettier, Kubernetes and JavaScript ones.
Anyone else face this issue? Or have any suggestions?
I tried removing almost all the extensions to see if there was a problematic one.

Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.
